# Basic math with parent cell value

Tags: jquery, html, math, html-table

I have a table with id values and an image in each cell.
So far my code displays the cell id when the user clicks on that cell. It also 'un-displays' that id when the user clicks on the same cell again. What I'm now trying to do is assign the number 10 to my table class, so that when you click on the cell, it will display 10, or if you click on 2 cells it will display 20 but if you click one of the cells again it would subtract 10. I hope that's easy enough to understand.

Here's my code so far:
HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class='test' id='1'><img src='images/Dog.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='2'><img src='images/Cat.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='3'><img src='images/Mouse.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='4'><img src='images/Human.gif'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var clicked = [];
$('td.test').click(function() {
    var found = clicked.indexOf(this.id);       
    if(found !== -1) {
        clicked.splice(found, 1);       
    } else {
        clicked.push(this.id);
    }
    $('#output').text(clicked.join(','));
});
});
```

Comment: Just in case I wasn't clear enough. Anything with class 'test' would have a value of 10

Comment: `clicked.length * 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand you, but is this it:

```
$('#output').text(clicked.length*10);
```

Comment: Yes, although this doesn't display the cell id along with it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple. try the following

```
  var score = 0;

   $('td.test').click(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
           $this.addClass('clicked');
           score += 10;
       } else {
           $this.removeClass('clicked');
           score -= 10;
       }
       $('#output').text(score);
  });
```